# I want my android app to start when a phone receives a call and to get the incoming phone number

Tags: android

I want my android app to start when a phone receives a call and to get the incoming phone number, i what to be able to put button on the screen of the incoming call and before that to be able to get the number calling, it would be of much help i anyone can refer me to some examples or materials. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will toast and log the incomming number...

```
  public class CallReceiveD extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
      Log.w("DEBUG", state);
      if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        String phoneNumber = extras
            .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);


       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context,phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);toast.show();

        Log.w("DEBUG", phoneNumber);
      }
    }


}

      }
```

dont forget the manifest file 
               < receiver
               android:name=".CallReceiveD">
             
                < action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

```
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a `broadcastlistener` in your `AndroidManifet.xml` You must setup your intent to listen for [`android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)
Then you get the phone state from the intent with `intent.getExtraString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)`  . If it's `OFFHOOK` or `RINGING` then a call has come in and you can get the phone number from the intent with [`intent.getExtraString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)